# CSS Ending animation?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

So I can easily make an animation when the class is loaded like this:

```
@keyframes dropin {
    from {top: -100px;}
    to {top: 0;}
}
.menu {
    display: none;
    animation: dropin .4s;
}
```

So when I click a button, a javascript executes and changes the `display:none` attribute to `block` and it plays the fadein animation.

However. When it changes back to `display: none`, there's no animation. Is there a way to fix this in css? If not; how can I do it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS animation only plays when the element becomes visible. For your case I would recommend using `transition` in order to fade in and out.
Try using `transition: opacity 0.4s;` for your `.menu` and Change the opacity using Javascript or jQuery.

By the way, if you're using jQuery, you can just do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("button").click(function() {
        $(".menu").fadeToggle(400);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Display: none` is different from `opacity: 0`.

Try to use `opacity: 0` instead of `Display: none`

Comment: I'm aware of this. The display:none; is for the javascript. I guess I used a wrong animation for the example. Updated!

Answer (score 0):

when it changes back, do not set the display none immediatly but use a timeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //set display none here
}, 400) //400 = 0.4s
```

[note: you should clear the timeout before making the 'appear' animation again]

Comment: So there's no way to do this in pure css, like the initial animation?

Comment: the display change is not performed in css anyway right ?

Comment: Correct, that's just js

Answer (score 0):

Display is one step change therefore you cant animate it is either one of block or none in this case. So you should use opacity instead. by using this css and toggling class animated you can get desired result.

```
.menu {
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}

.animated {
  opacity:1;
}
```

After your update on question you can still do that by changing 'opacity' with 'top'